# Enum switch in Java

Tags: arrays, list, for-loop, enums, switch-statement

I have this Java class where I am writing the code for applying the overrides. I want to know if using ENUM is appropriate or if I need to use the switch case, how can I use it? Also, I have the for loop that I need to use as a common block of code for each override type. Apart from that, I do have few separate fields that I need to code for each override type.

```
    public class EWFMService
    {
    private WorkbrainSystemAccessService wsa = new WorkbrainSystemAccessService();

private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(EWFMService.class);
private final static String ovrCalcGrp = "ovrCalcGrp";
private DBConnection conn = null;
private int empId;
private Date ovrDate;
private String ovrTime;
private String ovrAction;



public List<EWFMServiceData> getProcessEWFMOverrides(String userName, String password, List<EWFMServiceInputData> inputData)
throws WSApplicationException{      

    logger.debug("EWFM Service");       
    wsa.logOn(userName, password);    

    List<EWFMServiceData> returnList = new ArrayList<EWFMServiceData> ();
    logger.debug("userName = " + userName);

    DBConnection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
        conn = new DBConnection(ConnectionManager.getConnection());

    for (int i = 0; i < inputData.size(); i++) 
    {
```

Here I want to retrieve the emp_id from the database, store the value in a variable and be able to use the variable in the rest of my program. How do I do it? To retrieve the emp_id, I am using the following query.

```
        conn = new DBConnection(ConnectionManager.getConnection());
        String sql = "SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEE_HISTORY"
                + " WHERE EMP_VAL2 = **This is where I want to use the variable in which the values of emp_id will be stored. There can be more than 100 emp_ids**"
                + " AND SYSDATE BETWEEN EMPHIST_START_DATE AND      EMPHIST_END_DATE";


        EWFMServiceInputData inData = (EWFMServiceInputData)    inputData.get(i);
        OverrideType ot = OverrideType.getOverrideType(inData.getRecordType());
        logger.debug("override type = " + ot.toString());           
        logger.debug("inputData ["+i+"] = " + inData.toString());

       OverrideAccess oa = new OverrideAccess(conn);
        OverrideData ovr = new OverrideData();
        ovr.setOvrUdf4(inData.getReferenceId().toString());
        if (ovrAction.equals("APPLY")) {
            ovr.setOvrStatus(OverrideData.PENDING);
```

Here I want to determine the Action. If it is Apply, then I need to find out the recordType. So basically branch it out for each recordType using if else statements or enum as I believe switch doesn't support Java 1.5 which is what I am using. Then for each recordType, I branch out and write the appropriate code corresponding to that recordType. If Action is CANCEL, then I just write  the following code.

```
        } else if (ovrAction.equals("CANCEL")) {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM OVERRIDE"
                    + " WHERE OVR_UDF4 = ?"
                    + " AND OVRTYP_ID = ?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()); {
                ovr.assignByName(rs);
                ovr.setUpdated(false);
                ovr.setRetrieved(true);
                ovr.setOvrStatus(OverrideData.CANCEL);
                oa.save(ovr);                                   
            }
        }           
        ovr.setEmpId(empId);
        String strOvrDate = inData.getOvrStartDate();

        ovr.setOvrStartDate(DateHelper.parseDate(strOvrDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"));


        if (ovrStartTime != null) {
            ovr.setOvrStartTime(ovrTime);
        }
        Object ovrEndDate;
        if (ovrEndDate != null) {
            ovr.setOvrEndDate(ovrDate);
        }
        Object ovrEndTime;
        if (ovrEndTime!= null) {
            ovr.setOvrEndTime(ovrTime);
        }
        ovr.setOvrComment(inData.getOvrComments());
        ovr.setWbuName(inData.getWbuName());
        ovr.setWbuNameActual(inData.getWbuNameActual());
        ovr.setOvrNewValue("VAC");
        ovr.setOvrCreateDate(new Date());
        ovr.setOvrtypId(103);
        oa.insert(ovr);
        RuleEngine.runCalcGroup(conn,
                empId,
                ovrDate,
                ovrDate);   
        //COMMON BLOCK ENDS HERE
        EWFMServiceData outData = new EWFMServiceData();
        outData.setReferenceId(inData.getReferenceId());            

        String [] status = {"SUCCESS", "ERROR", "LOCKED", "EXCEPTION"};
        Random ran = new Random();
        String gen = status[ran.nextInt(status.length)];
        logger.debug("Status is"  + status );
        outData.setStatus(gen);         
        if (gen.equals("SUCCESS")){
         outData.setErrorDetails("");
        } else if (gen.equals("ERROR")) {
            outData.setErrorDetails("Usage of time code VAC is not allowed; balance is insufficient." + " error");
        } else if (gen.equals("LOCKED")) {
            outData.setErrorDetails("Timesheet cannot be edited because it is locked for payroll close." + "locked");
        } else if (gen.equals("EXCEPTION")) {
            outData.setErrorDetails("{ML}QR_INCORRECT_CONDITION_PARAMETER{/ML}Error in condition AWA Is Self Override Condition: java.lang.NullPointerException{ARGS}AWA Is Self Override Conditionjava.lang.NullPointerException{/ARGS" + "exception");
        }
        returnList.add(outData);
    } 
    }catch (Exception e){
    logger.error("Error occured",e);
    throw new WSApplicationException("Error retrieved",e);
}finally{
    SQLUtil.cleanUp(conn, ps, rs);
}

    wsa.logOff();

    logger.debug("inputData+ ");

    return returnList;

}



   // I need to know if writing enum is okay or can I just write a switch    case above in the for loop and branch each override type and declare their individual variables there? What's the best way? Can someone help me with the code?
   public enum OverrideType {
   WORKDETAIL,
   WORKPREMIUM,
   EMPLOYEESCHEDULE,
   EMPLOYEE;

   public static OverrideType getOverrideType(String recordType) {
       if(recordType == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Record Type cannot be null");
       }
       if(recordType.equals("Work Detail")) {


           return WORKDETAIL;

       } else if (recordType.equals("Work Premium")) {
           return WORKPREMIUM;
       } else if (recordType.equals("Schedule")) {
           return EMPLOYEESCHEDULE;
       } else if (recordType.equals("Shift Pattern")) {
           return EMPLOYEE;
       } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Record Type cannot be" + recordType);
       }
   }

   } 

   }
```

THE OTHER FIELDS I NEED TO INCLUDE ARE AS FOLLOWS:

1. FOR WORKDETAIL, I NEED TO USE TIMECODE OF FORMAT THAT IS SENT BY THE CLIENT.
2. FOR WORK PREMIUM, I NEED TO USE TIMECODE OF FORMAT THAT IS SENT BY THE CLIENT AND ANOTHER FIELD IS MINUTES THAT GIVES THE NUMBER OF MINUTES WHICH IS ALSO SENT BY THE CLIENT.

Comment: Tips for good posts: (1) don't mark questions as urgent. Volunteers will answer them at their leisure, and your question is not more important than others; (2) don't use all caps, as it is widely regarded as shouting; (3) proof-read your question to ensure code is formatted correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, using enums is appropriate, especially if you have a defined set of possible types.

You can also add behavior to the enums, which could make your enum a little bit more sophisticated:

```
public enum OverrideType {
        WORKDETAIL("Work Detail"),
        WORKPREMIUM("Work Premium"),
        EMPLOYEESCHEDULE("Schedule"),
        EMPLOYEE("Shift Pattern");

        private String identifier;

        private OverrideType(String identifier){
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        public static OverrideType getOverrideType(String recordType) {

            if(recordType == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Record Type cannot be null");
            }

            for (OverrideType ot : OverrideType.values()) {
                if (recordType.equals(ot.identifier)) {
                    return ot;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
}
```

The following example shows how to use an interface in enums or an abstract method definition:

```
public enum OverrideType implements OverrideTypeIF {
    WORKDETAIL("Work Detail") {
        public int getKey() {
            return 0;
        }
    },
    WORKPREMIUM("Work Premium") {
        public int getKey() {
            return 0;

        }
    },

    EMPLOYEESCHEDULE("Schedule") {
        public int getKey() {
            return 0;

        }
    },
    EMPLOYEE("Shift Pattern") {
        public int getKey() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void myInterfaceMethod() {
            // do type specific behavior
        }
    };

    private String identifier;

    private OverrideType(String identifier){
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public abstract int getKey();

    public void myInterfaceMethod() {
        // do default behavior
    }

    public static OverrideType getOverrideType(String recordType) {

        if(recordType == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Record Type cannot be null");
        }

        for (OverrideType ot : OverrideType.values()) {
            if (recordType.equals(ot.identifier)) {
                return ot;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public interface OverrideTypeIF {
    void myInterfaceMethod();
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to Java.. Do you mind explaining how I can use the code above the enum part? Can I use a switch there and create a case for each override type? And under each case, I can write its own fields while keeping the common code same and just using its reference in the cases?

Comment: I don't know exactly, what you mean.

Comment: @codejava: you can implement interfaces oder define abstract methods and overwrite/implement them specifically for every enum entry. I extended my previous answer, so please have look.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have edited my question. Could you please help. Appreciate it greatly.